# How do I debug my SSO SAML integration with zendesk

Tags: node.js, express, single-sign-on, saml, zendesk

I am setting up a single sign on SAML service with zendesk. I am writing a custom SAML server using node/express and using [node-samlp](https://github.com/auth0/node-samlp).

Zendesk is the SP,
My SAML server has its own IdP

The user steps are as follows:

Navigates to *account*.zendesk.com and gets redirected to *account*.com/login?SAMLRequest=asdfasdfafsd

User then enters credentials and posts to the node server.
At the server I am able to parse* the SAMLRequest, verify the user and give the user a SAMLResponse.

The user receives from the node server a SAMLResponse and is redirected to: *account*.zendesk.com?SAMLResponse=asdfasdf&RelayState=xxx

At that point the user gets a page not found. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, at this point I'm guessing that my SAMLResponse is either badly formatted or I am redirecting the user to the wrong address.

PS: initially samlp didn't work right out of the box, I forked the repo and updated a couple dependencies and it started to work.

*I was unable to parse the SAMLRequest from zendesk initially. When I used decodeURIComponent on the query param, there were new line characters and white spaces which I replaced with a '+' which made it work. Then I realized that their query param seems to not be URI encoded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as @hans-z already mentioned, a SAMLResponse is always sent over **POST**! You can trigger this browser POST by serving a page that automatically submits a form (containing the SAMLResponse) on page load (through JavaScript).

Since you're sending over **POST**, your SAMLResponse should **not** be **URL encoded** anymore.

Comment: Thanks Karsten, I am a noob at anything server related. I appreciate your answer! Will give it a go!

Answer (score 2):

For one thing there is no such thing as a SAML Redirect Binding for the SAML Response. You can send the SAML Response as a form-encoded parameter in an HTTP POST, but you cannot pass it as a query parameter in a redirect. Your SAML IDP implementation is not spec-compliant and Zendesk may be rejecting the message because of that.

See http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf#page=16 :

> 5. Identity Provider issues  to Service Provider In step 5, the identity provider issues a  message to be delivered by
>      the user agent to the service provider. Either the HTTP POST, or HTTP
>      Artifact binding can be used to transfer the message to the service
>      provider through the user agent. The message may indicate an error, or
>      will include (at least) an authentication assertion. The HTTP Redirect
>      binding MUST NOT be used, as the response will typically exceed the
>      URL length permitted by most user agents.

Comment: I'm not so sure... The spec on [Bindings](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf#page=15) says you can send a response via redirect, and provides an example of such on [page 21](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf#page=21)...

Comment: added a pointer to the web sso profile rules that override the binding spec

Comment: And, as Hans pointed out to me behind the scenes... [SAML Profiles for Browser SSO](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf#page=16) says not to use the redirect for the response. Damn the twisty turny specs! (Thanks, Hans!)